# How to render CKEditor5 toolbar buttons in a new row instead of the main row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

[image: CKEditor 5]

I integrated CKEditor5 in my create react app from the source. Now, I want to render the overflowed buttons in a new row of the toolbar but they are displayed in a separate menu item.

How can I display buttons in a new row instead of the main row?

Here's my config:

```
ClassicEditor.defaultConfig = {
  toolbar: {
    items: [
      'Essentials',
      'heading',
      'Mathtype',
      'ChemType',
      '|',
      'bold',
      'italic',
      'underline',
      ....
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a list of the toolbar items that you are using?  I am struggling to find a comprehensive list of available toolbar items.  Perhaps you could provide your entire config?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true` property of [toolbar](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorconfig-EditorConfig.html#member-toolbar) like this:

```js
toolbar: {
    items: [ ... ],
    shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use '-' to make a line break and render items in multiple lines in toolbar

```
const config = {
    toolbar: {
        items: [ 'bold', 'italic', '|', 'undo', 'redo', '-', 'numberedList', 'bulletedList' ],
        viewportTopOffset: 30,
        shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
    }
};
```