# classic ck editor not responding on smaller width browser sizes

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, responsive

am editing data on a modal whereby on clicking the edit button in the page a modal appears.on the modal i have a div that i have appended a text area using ck-ediotr 5 that shows the details from the database.the backend part works very well,the issue am getting is here,the ckeditor 5 texarea is not resonsive based on the viewpoints.it overflows i have tried adding a "form-controll" class in the text area but still its not responsive.here is an image of how it overflows
[image: textarea overflow]

when i remove the ck-editor integration the text area works correct.i have not been able to understand where the css bug is coming from.what might the the source of the error of the text are not being responsive when itegrated with ck editor

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation one can solve this using toolbar rearrangement this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61976625/how-to-render-ckeditor5-toolbar-buttons-in-a-new-row-instead-of-the-main-row) helped to solve the issue